# Viewing a PDF from S3 bucket using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I could be able to Highlight/upload/download the PDF files on the S3 bucket programmatically using the boto3 client. However, **I want to view the PDF files in the browser**. If I upload the files using the AWS Console, the public URL allows me to view the file.
**But if I upload the files using AWS SDK, (programmatically) and I use the public UR, instead of viewing, it downloads the file.**

Are there any parameters to be set while uploading the file programmatically so that it can be viewed in the browser?
Following are my code snippets.

```
# Accessing files from s3 my_s3_bucket
import boto3
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
from io import BytesIO
import os
import fitz


aws_access_key_id = os.environ['aws_access_key_id']
aws_secret_access_key = os.environ['aws_secret_access_key']
aws_region_name = os.environ['aws_region_name']

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='default')
s3 = session.client('s3')

print('Boto client created successfully')

bucket_name = 'my-bucket'
item_name = 'Sample.pdf'

s3_object = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name,Key=item_name)
body = s3_object['Body']

fs = body.read()
pdf=fitz.open("pdf", stream=BytesIO(fs))
pdfPage = pdf[42]
    
es_highlighted_result = ['line 1', 
                         'line 2' , 
                         'line 3']
for line in es_highlighted_result:
    r1 = pdfPage.search_for(line)
    pdfPage.addHighlightAnnot(r1)

output_buffer = BytesIO()
pdf.save(output_buffer)
output_filepath = 'my-path-to-file'
output_file = output_filepath + item_name
new_bytes = pdf.write()

#----------------------------------------
# Logic to write the file on local and then upload
# ------------------------------------
with open(output_file,mode='wb') as f:
        f.write(output_buffer.getbuffer())

upload_file_bucket = bucket_name
upload_file_key = str(output_file)
s3.upload_file(output_file,upload_file_bucket,upload_file_key)

#------Tried this also --------------
# s3.Bucket(bucket_name).put_object(Key=output_file, Body=new_bytes)
# s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name,Key=output_file,Body=new_bytes,ACL='public-read')
#----------------------------------------
print('File uploaded successfully')

url = s3.generate_presigned_url(ClientMethod='get_object', 
    Params={'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': output_file},ExpiresIn=3600)

print(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ContentType and ContentDisposition attributes, Please check sample below

```
s3.upload_file(
'FILE_NAME', 'BUCKET_NAME', 'OBJECT_NAME',
ExtraArgs={ 'ContentDisposition' : 'inline',
    'ContentType':'application/pdf'}
```

)

Comment: This worked for me :

s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name,Key=filename,Body=new_bytes,ACL='public-read',ContentDisposition='inline',           ContentType='application/pdf')